# Error using username token in WSO2 Microintegrator 4

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I am migrating services from EI 6 to MI. These soap services are secured using username token. I have updated the policy with the new library:

```
<rampart:tokenStoreClass>org.wso2.micro.integrator.security.extensions.SecurityTokenStore</rampart:tokenStoreClass>
```

But I still get the following error when launching a request:

```
WARN {Loader} - org.wso2.carbon.security.util.SecurityTokenStore java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.security.util.SecurityTokenStore
```

Do I need to do some more updates in the proxy or policy, beside the described above?

Regards

Comment: org.wso2.micro.integrator.security.extensions.SecurityTokenStore is the correct tokenStoreclass for the MI. Could you please check whether you have saved the artefacts before creating the capp

Comment: yes, I can even see the service deployed.